# Reselect. React. Which is the best way of usage the Reselect to gets the maximum perfomance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reselect

I'm not so far ago have met with new to me package as **Reselect**. I read carefully the official docs and already have an experience with my firsts `selectors`. But only one thing that I cannot understand - which is the best code architecture of implementation `selectors` in the components to create the right memoized selectors?

So, I have a 2 basic part of the code (*do not be scared of the so huge code amount in this post, it's just mocked, please looks only on code logic structure*):

1.The First case, component holds the logic that responses for the right `render()` of the component inside it own *(classic case)*. It has connected to the `Reselect selectors` and receives only calculates values that `Reselect` throws from the incoming Redux `state` to this component that previously has been cached in it.

```
// imports Reselect selectors calculated value
import { ID, additionalInfo} from './selectors'

class Row extends Component {
  // component the responce for right render logic of the component based on Reselect values
  _progress = (ID, additionalInfo) => {
    const { statusEffects = [] } = additionalInfo
    const { timePercent: timeDisabled = 0 } = statusEffects[1] || {}
    const inactiveRows = rowID === 1 || rowID === 2
  
    const isDisabled = inactiveRows ? false : statusEffects[1] && statusEffects[1].disabled
    const isStatus = (statusEffects[1] && statusEffects[1].title) === 'Checkpoint'
  
  
    const progressOff = inactiveRows ? 0 : parseInt(timeDisabled.toFixed())
    const statusCheckpoint = isDisabled ? `${progressOff}%` : `${progressOff}%`
    const statusG = isDisabled ? `${progressOff}%` : `${progressOff}%`
    const status = isStatus ? statusCheckpoint : statusG
  
    return {
      isDisabled,
      progressOff,
      status
    }
  }

  render() {
    // calculated values inside own component method based on values from Reselect selectors
    const { isDisabled, progressOff, status } = this._progress(ID, additionalInfo)

    return ( 
      //...some view logic 
      {isDisabled + progressOff + status}
    )
  }
}
```

2.The second case, the component has a separated logic that response for the render of the `render()` method in `selectors file`. It has migrated in `selectors` file inside the `Reselect` `createSelector` wrapper. Where `selectors` calculates and cashes all data from Redux state and component logic func and throw on component only the final output values, directly in the render method of the component.

```
// createSelector logic with all component render logic
export const progress = createSelector([getId, getAdditionalInfo], (ID, additionalInfo) => {
  const { statusEffects = [] } = additionalInfo
  const { timePercent: timeDisabled = 0 } = statusEffects[1] || {}
  const inactiveRows = rowID === 1 || rowID === 2

  const isDisabled = inactiveRows ? false : statusEffects[1] && statusEffects[1].disabled
  const isStatus = (statusEffects[1] && statusEffects[1].title) === 'Checkpoint'


  const progressOff = inactiveRows ? 0 : parseInt(timeDisabled.toFixed())
  const statusCheckpoint = isDisabled ? `${progressOff}%` : `${progressOff}%`
  const statusG = isDisabled ? `${progressOff}%` : `${progressOff}%`
  const status = isStatus ? statusCheckpoint : statusG

  return {
    isDisabled,
    progressOff,
    status
  }
})

// component that gets calculated reselect values
class Row extends Component {
  render() {
    // recives the whole calculated values from Reselect selectors
    const { isDisabled, progressOff, status } = progress

    return ( 
      //...some view logic 
      {isDisabled + progressOff + status}
    )
```

> And what I want to ask - if there are some performance differences of such two ways of Reselect usage? Which one is best on your think:
>
> 1. Throw from `Reselect` on component only the calculated values from `selectors` that grabbed and cashed from Redux state
>
> or
>
> 2. Place all component `render` logic inside `Reselect` `createSelector` func and throw on the component only the final calculated values?

I'll be grateful you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a both cases are right. Obviously, it's no unequivocal answer to this question. You should use `reselect` for each calculation that you can spot in the `render` method of a Component.

Also, you can improve Reselect memoization on you own, please see this FAQ from official page: https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#q-the-default-memoization-function-is-no-good-can-i-use-a-different-one

I hope it will help you to understand what you want to do there.

Comment: Yes, now I understand my goal of using `reselect` memoization. Maybe I posted here it in a little bit awkward form. :)